# moving sprite at mouse location jittery

Tags: c++, sfml

I am trying to move the sprite to the mouse's location, and what I get works, but it is pretty jittery [the result](https://gyazo.com/e5e34c641de0602ab498714ec9f7ec7c)

Here is my main:

```
int main() {
Game chessGame;
RenderWindow wnd(VideoMode(400, 400), "Chess Game");

while (wnd.isOpen()) {
    Event event;
    while (wnd.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == Event::Closed) {
            wnd.close();
        }

    }
    wnd.clear();
    chessGame.printGame(&wnd);
    wnd.display();
}

return 0;
```

}

The important part of `printGame()`:

```
// more stuff up there but it's not neccessary

// txt is the texture of the chess piece
Sprite tool(txt);
        FloatRect toolRec = tool.getGlobalBounds();

        tool.setScale(window->getSize().x / 8 / toolRec.width  , window->getSize().y / 8 / toolRec.height);
        Mouse m;
        Vector2i pos =  m.getPosition(*window);
        tool.setPosition(pos.x, pos.y);
        window->draw(tool); // drawing the sprite
```

Comment: I don't see it [jittering](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/jittering) in the traditional sense of the word.  What is "jittery"?  What is your actual question?

Comment: likely the mouse keeps moving slightly.  it might not be perfectly stable.  or you might be calling the function way too frequently, so it keeps re-drawing it all the time.

Comment: Looks to me like it is somehow being drawn multiple times before being displayed to the window. Something appears to be wrong about the clear-draw-display cycle.I feel like you need to show us more of your code. Maybe the tiles in the back are also "jittering" but we can't tell because they're static? My two cents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very general answer, but you will have to change a lot of your code anyway to fix your problem: **do not mix render and update code**.

Create one method to draw the current state of your game. Create *another* method to update the current state of your game.

For example, your `Render()` method renders a chesspiece. Your `Update()` method changes the position of the chesspiece.

Why not have both in the same method? You want to draw as many times as possible to make your game look smooth. You want high FPS (frames drawn per second). **But** you want to update your game state not at the speed of drawing, but at a constant speed. For example your chesspieces takes 2 seconds to move. You don't want sombody with a slower graphics card to wait longer, or somebody with a faster computer to not see it at all because the animation took only 20 milliseconds. You want it to take 2 seconds on *both* systems.

Your jittering is most likely an effect of mixing up drawing and gamestate. Fix that first.

Comment: btw, I have a function that updates the game, it just isnt there. I'm trying out the position of the piece when I use it

Comment: thanks, making the game wait for a couple of seconds worked! kudos for the solution